# PHP eAccelerator include_path issue

Tags: php, eaccelerator

OK guys, I have a weird problem,

I have been using set_include_path before eaccelerator and all workded great but now I can't get it to working, its not setting my path and also sometimes when use get_include_path to append old one before setting new one get_include_path return binary string rather than string.

Any ideas?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath('/../your_path1'),
    realpath('/../your_path2'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Comment: have switched to APC, no problems there.